# Postfix mail server & dovecot can send but not receive

Tags: debian, email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

Today i created a mail server with this tutorial : https://www.milbako.com/e-mail-avec-postfix-dovecot-et-mysql/
I can send mails (detected as spam, but it works), but if i send me an email from my gmail adress, it won't work...

This is my main.cf file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2


# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/cpmtech.fr-0001/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/cpmtech.fr-0001/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous

# Authentication
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

# Voir /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz dans le paquet postfix-doc pour plus de détails.
# informations sur l’activation de SSL dans le client smtp.

# Restrictions
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks,
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
 reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks,
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
 reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
 reject_unlisted_recipient,
 reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks,
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 reject_non_fqdn_sender,
 reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks,
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 defer_unauth_destination

# Voir /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz dans le paquet postfix-doc pour plus de détails.
# informations sur l’activation de SSL dans le client smtp.

myhostname = cpmtech.fr
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydomain = cpmtech.fr
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# Remettre la livraison locale au LMTP de Dovecot et lui dire où stocker le courrier
virtual_transport = dovecot

# Domaines virtuels, utilisateurs et alias
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,
 mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf

# Encore plus de restrictions et de paramètres MTA
disable_vrfy_command = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
#smtpd_etrn_restrictions = reject
#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
#smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
#smtpd_hard_error_limit = 1
smtpd_timeout = 30s
smtp_helo_timeout = 15s
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 15s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 40
minimal_backoff_time = 180s
maximal_backoff_time = 3h

# Codes de rejet de réponse
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 550
non_fqdn_reject_code = 550
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550

#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
#myhostname = cpmtech.fr
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#mydestination = cpmtech.fr, localhost.cpmtech.fr, localhost
#mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
#mailbox_size_limit = 0
#recipient_delimiter = +
#inet_protocols = all
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mynetworks_style = subnet
#recipient_canonical_maps =
#relayhost = 
#inet_interfaces = all
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

If i want to read logs, /var/log/ do not contain Postfix logs

Thanks for your help !

Comment: smtp.cpmtech.fr does not respond on port 25, it's unsurprising mail can't be delivered.

Comment: Have you forwarded port 25 to the IP Address Postfix is running on and allowed port 25 in your firewall? Depending on OS your log file may be /var/log/maillog

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i be sure that my 25 port is opened ? And how can i open it if it's closed ? (I'm on Debian 10).
I searched on the web but i didn't really understood.

Comment: I tried this website : https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ with my VPS ip adress and it's said opened. 
What can i check now ?

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into the question. Either post it as an answer if you found it yourself, or ask someone who gave you the final tip to post their comment as an answer. Accept it either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found how to correct my problem.

My problem was on Dovecot & Postfix configuration.
My first problem was on SASL, postfix was unable to connect to SASL folder.
To resolve my problem, i installed rsyslog and restart postfix to show logs and i follow each problem to resolve mine.

Thanks for who helped me !

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: I've got many problems, and the solutions was to get logs ready to use and correct each bug with Google.